# Piping to python indentation

Tags: python, pipe

while piping a process to a python program like so

```
 cat someFile | python -c "<Python code over here>"
```

How does one account for indentation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple option is to add the indentation:

```
$ echo foo | python -c '
> if True:
>  print "yes"
> '
```